# Need to select 1 row from each group in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

am trying to do this query. This is what I have.

My table is: Table

```
QId    InternalId      type.     priority       userid
100       100              1            0                X101
100       100              1            1                X102
100       100              2            0                X103
100       100              2            0                X104
100       100              2            0                X105
100       100              3            0                X106
100       100              3            0                X107
101       101              2            1                X114
101       101              2            0                X115
101       101              3            0                X116
101       101              3            0                X117
```

For QId and InternalId we have type 1,2,3. I need 1 row for each group based type. Here condition is if priority is 1 then we need take that record. if priority is not set need to take first record.

I need result like below table

```
QId    InternalId      type.     priority       userid
100       100              1            1                X102
100       100              2            0                X103
100       100              3            0                x106
101       101              2            1                X114
101       101              3            0                X116
```

Can you please help me out in this

Comment: *"am trying to do this query"* Show us your attempts

Comment: Define "first record". First record with respect to what?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by QId, InternalId, type order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by qid, internalid, type order by priority desc) as rn
from tablename
)A where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number()` window function

```
select t.* from (select *,row_number()over(partition by QId,InternalId,type order by case when priority=1 then 1 else 2 end) rn
) where t.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be `WITH TIES` like following.

```
select top 1 with ties *
from @table
order by row_number() over (partition by QId, InternalId, type order by (select 1))
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/UPCP93078)